# FRAPS alternative: Where to look and what for?

Tags: c++, video, video-capture, video-processing

later this year I'm going to have a lot of time on my hands, and I thought I'd start a "small" project for myself and release it as open source.

I'd like to code my own Fraps alternative. (or continue with Taksi http://taksi.sourceforge.net ).

Fraps is a video & sound recording programm, which captures the screen during gameplay. It has way more functions than I need and its commercial.

All I want is being able to record the screen / game I'm currently playing continuously including sound no other extras.

Now this is a new area for me, but not the programming languages. I thought I'll be using C++ (& others if needed).

What I need are hints where to look, and what to look for, where to read stuff rearding it. Etc. etc.

I hope y'all can help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some good info on the techniques used by FRAPS.

http://www.woodmann.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-11023.htm

Comment: Thanks thats a good start, but I'm looking more for literature, tutorials, guides and whatnot as to how recording works and how to programm it. 

How it in general works under Windows.

More like what APIs, Frameworks, Formats, Filesizes, Hooks, etc. etc. if you catch my drift.

Anything that gives me an idea how recording a screen/game in real-time during a gameplay session in the background works. Sound, Video, Resolution, Space, Uncompressed Formats, etc. etc.

Comment: 1+ interesting stuff. 

NoCanDo: Well for getting the frames from DirectX the first port of call should be the documentation for it?

Answer (score 3):

My company published a source code in C++ for hooking into DirectX to capture video and calculate FPS (audio is not included). It is available on github as [AVRecorderTool](https://github.com/nektra/AVRecorderTool).

Comment: You just need to compile the code and it works. We wrote an article giving an overview of the project at http://blog.nektra.com/main/2013/07/23/instrumenting-direct3d-applications-to-capture-video-and-calculate-frames-per-second/ if you have a specific question just drop it in the forum.