# Create a child window inside another application

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to write a bot in C++ for a PC game using the windows API. I've managed to find the process `HANDLE`, its `ID` and finally its `HWND`with `EnumWindows`. I've managed also to send messages to its window (using `SendMessage`) in order to simulate keystrokes. Since the game runs full screen I'd like to create a child window inside it with custom controls to switch on/off the bot easily but i'm having problems with it. I've tried to register a window class and create a window with the game's `HWND` as a parent but I can't see anything. This is the code I've used to create the child window (not working):

```
// ... Window class registering etc...

HWND hChild = CreateWindowEx(0, 
                             "MyWindowClass", 
                             "Title", 
                             WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 
                             0, 0, 100, 100, 
                             hParent, 
                             NULL, 
                             AHInstance, 
                             NULL); // Parent is a valid window handle from another process
```

Honestly I'm not a skilled windows API programmer, this whole thing is new to me. I'm not even sure if this is the right way to do such thing.

[Edit.] When i minimize/maximize the game my window shows correctly for a second or two. It seems that the game's rendering is happening after the rendering of my window. Any idea? And what about messages? Should i manage them or not? Is the game going to forward messages to my window?

Comment: You could try to validate that your parent hWnd is good with a utility like WinSpy: http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy-17

Comment: `SetWindowPos` to move the window into position. `SetParent` to set the child window of YOUR application to another application. You might have to make the window a child of your own first.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to have much success by running the code from a different process. Cross process parent/child relationships seldom work. Especially if the other process is not expecting it. This is not something you take on lightly. The capability only exists as a compatibility sop to 16 bit Windows. No place for that technique today.

It seems plausible to me that you don't need to parent the window in this way. If you don't need it to be a child of a window in the other process, don't do that.

If you do need it to be a child of the other process then you might be in trouble. Perhaps you could inject a DLL into the other process and create the window there. Also not without difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

Windows have [thread affinity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/10/10/479124.aspx).  This means that the thread that creates the window will be processing the messages for that window.  Furthermore, all windows in a parent-child chain should be processed by the same thread.  Otherwise, [bad things happen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx).

So - how is your code being run?  If it's a separate executable, you're going to be much better off leaving your window as a top-level window, and simply monitoring the target window for move events (using [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for example) and having your window move appropriately.

Otherwise, you're going to need to inject your code into the game executable, and have it create the windows on the appropriate thread.  I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Well, you are probably right, i'll try to keep the two applications separate and maybe disable fullscreen if my window won't be comfortable with it. Do you think it is possible to draw informations on the game window canvas? I know a lot of programs that can already do that (like FRAPS with FPS for example) but i'm still not sure, maybe they're doing the same trick with an invisible top level window

Comment: @napco Are you sure it's drawing on the same canvas, and not on (e.g.) a transparent (layered) top level window?  If you *really* need to draw on the same canvas, you have to be in the same process.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354360/fraps-alternative-where-to-look-and-what-for) for some pointers on how to do that.

Comment: This is the new link to the "Bad thing happen"
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683